# MongoDB Insufficient free space for journal files

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed a standalone mongo 2.6 in amazon ec2. The instance has reach the limit of disk space and it doesnt run now. I have set before the smallfiles=true in mongod.conf file, but for some reason this doesn't work neither. 
The log file says:

> 2015-03-12T19:41:26.881+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
>   2015-03-12T19:41:26.881+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 422MB available in /data/journal or use --smallfiles
>   2015-03-12T19:41:26.881+0000 [initandlisten] 
>   2015-03-12T19:41:26.881+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating

I tried to set journal path in another volume >

> sudo ln -s /journal /data/journal

But this doesn't work neither and logs the same error above :(

I want to mantain the /data (with all dbs files) in the same disk , I only want to move the journal path to another disk , is that possible?
Please , any help is welcome!

pd: I used before tune2fs for get more space , but now I don't have it.

Comment: StackOverflow is for topics related to programming only. For questions relating to database administration and configuration please ask on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ec2 has upgraded their storage limit volume , so does how I managed to workaround this problem.

Comment: Do you know any other solutions to this?

Comment: @sha1 Did you check this? http://wiredrevolution.com/system-administration/free-ext3-reserved-blocks-with-tune2fs