# Node App Starts But Not Listening on Port

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port

I am trying to troubleshoot a Node + Mongo app we have on an AWS EC2 instance.

It began with a crash. A brief investigation revealed that `mongod` process crashed. In trying to start it, we discovered that the errors were almost identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29019429/mongodb-insufficient-free-space-for-journal-files) issue.

Having successfully increased the disk space for the instance, we were able to start `mongod`.

However, when we start the app with `sudo pm2 start npm -- start`, it starts but does not seem to be listening on port 80.

Here is the output of `netstat -tulpn` command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40863               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::59195                    :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

As you can see, the MongoDB appears to be listening on port 27017. However, we cannot connect to it using Robomongo from our local machines.

What's more, as I mentioned above, the Node app does not seem to be listening. That is, we have tried starting it using `npm start`, `node app.js` and a couple of others to no avail.

My question is what may be going on and what can I do to troubleshoot it? The only idea I have at this point is to try accessing MongoDB on the server from the console and see if it works. I shall try that shortly. However, my understanding is that irrespective of whether DB works, the app itself should show some signs of life.

I can provide more details, if needed, especially from `app.js`.

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comment, I ran `ps -ef | grep -i node` with the following being its output:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i node
ec2-user  3179  3108  0 03:50 ?        00:00:11 node /home/ec2-user/the_app_in_question/app.js                  
root      5187  5181  0 04:07 ?        00:00:01 node ./bin/www
ec2-user 25925 25903  0 13:18 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i node
```

The 'netstat' command but with `sudo`:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5187/node           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2713/sendmail       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40863               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2246/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2754/mongod         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2664/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3073/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3031/sshd           
tcp        0      0 :::59195                    :::*                        LISTEN      2246/rpc.statd      
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      3073/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      3031/sshd
```

Inbound rules for this instance:

```
80  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
5432    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
8000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
22  tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
9775    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
20-21   tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
54763   tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
3000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
443 tcp 0.0.0.0/0   ✔
```

Comment: can you do a `ps -ef | grep -i node` just to ensure that the node process is running?

Comment: I edited the question to show you the results of this command.

Comment: it seems the node process that you have for port 80 is run by root. can you run the netstat command with sudo to see if it lists the port 80.

Comment: I added another edit. It looks like a node process is running, but on port 3000. I am also including our inbound rules for this instance to show that port 3000 is listenable.

Comment: Another bit of information I have just discovered is that if I navigate directly to `http://app.url:3000`, I am able to to see that it is working. The question is why `http://app.url` does not work. Perhaps there was some redirect that disappeared after the crash and/or adjustment of the disk space?

Comment: Did you restart the instance at some point? It sounds like you may have had an `iptables` port redirect rule forwarding port `80` to port `3000` but the rule wasn't persisted so it was lost on reboot.

Comment: @MarkB You are probably right. This app ran for ~1.5 years without a restart. We probably forgot how it was set up.